# Python - if SystaxError

Tags: python, if-statement, sys

I have problem with this if.
I found I can use `in` in if-statement.

```
if "log" in sys.argv[1:]
```

Syntax Error

Comment: you are missing colon `:` at the end of `if` statement. Your line should be: `if "log" in sys.argv[1:]:`

Comment: @Dortik : In the error shown, the error location marker `^` is at the end of statement. That generally is indicative of this common error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't show us the code surrounding the if-statement, we cannot know for sure what the problem is. If I were to make a guess however, I'd say you're missing a colon:

```
if "log" in sys.argv[1:]:
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html) for compound statements (like ifs):

> Each clause header begins with a uniquely identifying keyword and ends with a colon

Comment: Yes, this is it I look hour to code where is mistake and you found it in 1 minute. Thanks you in advance